# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.callbacks' has no attribute 'BackupAndRestore'

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback

I tried to use `tf.keras.callbacks.BackupAndRestore` but it showed error that `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.callbacks' has no attribute 'BackupAndRestore'`

Can help me to solve it?

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This AttributeError is because you are using **TensorFlow<2.8** to import `BackupAndRestore` api.

`BackupAndRestore` is available as `tf.keras.callbacks.BackupAndRestore` in TensorFlow 2.8 and later version of TensorFlow. Please check this [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.8.0) for the same.

Between TensorFlow version 2.3 to 2.7,

> `BackupAndRestore` was in experimental phase and would be accessible
> using
> `from tensorflow.keras.callbacks.experimental import BackupAndRestore`

So, Please try importing the `BackupAndRestore` api as per the installed TensorFlow version in your system or you can upgrade the TensorFlow version to >=2.8 using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` to use `tf.keras.callbacks.BackupAndRestore`.

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Noon Kamonchat, Could you please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you? Thank you.